# How to set selenide properties?

Tags: properties, selenide

I cant set property with a System.setProperty

```
System.setProperty("selenide.browserSize", "300x200");
```

After this command browserSize is not changed

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenide build in Configurations.
Import for Configurations:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
```

Configurations to run Chrome:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\chromedriver.exe");
Configuration.browser = "chrome";
Configuration.browserSize ="300x200"; //1920x1080
```

You can also set your browser maximized with next command:

```
Configuration.startMaximized = true;
```

Configuration command has very good functions in it like browser "headless" running, "holdBrowserOpen" and "fastSetValue"

Answer (score 0):

Try this as maven parameter

```
-Dselenide.browserSize=300x200
```